# Assigning List<class> to a GridView as DataSource gives error

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

1. I have created a class **Car** that returns collection classes.
2. In Page_Load event, I am calling the function in Cars class to get result. And assigning the results to a GridView.

Doing so gives me error- *"The data source for GridView with id 'gv' did not have any properties or attributes from which to generate columns.  Ensure that your data source has content."*

**Here is my Car class**-

```
class Car
    {
        public Car()
        {

        }

        public string Model;
        public string CarType;
        public List<Accessories> Accessory=new List<Accessories>();
        public string Price;

        public List<Car> GetCars()
        {
            // Car 1
            Car Car1 = new Car();
            Car1.Model = "Range Rover Evoque";
            Car1.CarType = "SUV";
            Car1.Price = "70 Lac";

            Car.Accessories car1Interior = new Car.Accessories
            {
                LetherSeats = "Front and Back",
                Music = "CD Player",
                GPS = "Touch Screen"
            };

            Car.Accessories car1Ext = new Car.Accessories
            {
                LetherSeats = "Front Only",
                Music = "No",
                GPS = "No"
            };

            Car1.Accessory.Add(car1Interior);
            Car1.Accessory.Add(car1Ext);

            // Car 2
            Car Car2 = new Car();
            Car2.Model = "Lamborghini Sesto Elemento";
            Car2.CarType = "Racing";

            Car.Accessories car2Interior = new Car.Accessories
            {
                LetherSeats = "Front and Back",
                Music = "None",
                GPS = "Touch Screen"
            };
            Car.Accessories car2Ext = new Car.Accessories
            {
                FogLights = "None",
                Spolier = "Yes",
                NeonLight = "Yes"
            };

            Car2.Accessory.Add(car2Interior);
            Car2.Accessory.Add(car2Ext);

            Car2.Price = "2 Crore";

            List<Car> cars = new List<Car>();
            cars.Add(Car1);
            cars.Add(Car2);

            return cars;
        }


        public class Accessories
        {
            private string _LeatherSeats;
            private string _GPS;
            private string _Music;
            private string _FogLights;
            private string _Spoiler;
            private string _NeonLight;

            public string LetherSeats { get { return _LeatherSeats; } set { _LeatherSeats = value; } }
            public string GPS { get { return _GPS; } set { _GPS = value; } }
            public string Music { get { return _Music; } set { _Music = value; } }
            public string FogLights { get { return _FogLights; } set { _FogLights = value; } }
            public string Spolier { get { return _Spoiler; } set { _Spoiler = value; } }
            public string NeonLight { get { return _NeonLight; } set { _NeonLight = value; } }
        }
    }
```

**And here is Page_Load method-**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        Car wr = new Car();
        gv.DataSource = wr.GetCars();
        gv.DataBind();
    }
}
```

ASPX page-

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Post the definition of your gridview.

Comment: ...any properties or attributes...

Comment: @FelipeOriani GridView will Automatically generate columns. However, I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using properties, not only the public attribute. You could also use a `static` method to get a list, since it is not part of the `Car` object. For sample:

```
public class Car
{
    public Car()
    {
        Acessory = new List<Accessories>();
    }

    public string Model { get; set; }
    public string CarType { get; set; }
    public List<Accessories> Accessory  { get; set; }
    public string Price { get; set; }

    public static List<Car> GetCars()
    {
        // Car 1
        Car Car1 = new Car();
        Car1.Model = "Range Rover Evoque";
        Car1.CarType = "SUV";
        Car1.Price = "70 Lac";

        Car.Accessories car1Interior = new Car.Accessories
        {
            LetherSeats = "Front and Back",
            Music = "CD Player",
            GPS = "Touch Screen"
        };

        Car.Accessories car1Ext = new Car.Accessories
        {
            LetherSeats = "Front Only",
            Music = "No",
            GPS = "No"
        };

        Car1.Accessory.Add(car1Interior);
        Car1.Accessory.Add(car1Ext);

        // Car 2
        Car Car2 = new Car();
        Car2.Model = "Lamborghini Sesto Elemento";
        Car2.CarType = "Racing";

        Car.Accessories car2Interior = new Car.Accessories
        {
            LetherSeats = "Front and Back",
            Music = "None",
            GPS = "Touch Screen"
        };
        Car.Accessories car2Ext = new Car.Accessories
        {
            FogLights = "None",
            Spolier = "Yes",
            NeonLight = "Yes"
        };

        Car2.Accessory.Add(car2Interior);
        Car2.Accessory.Add(car2Ext);

        Car2.Price = "2 Crore";

        List<Car> cars = new List<Car>();
        cars.Add(Car1);
        cars.Add(Car2);

        return cars;
    }


    public class Accessories
    {
        private string _LeatherSeats;
        private string _GPS;
        private string _Music;
        private string _FogLights;
        private string _Spoiler;
        private string _NeonLight;

        public string LetherSeats { get { return _LeatherSeats; } set { _LeatherSeats = value; } }
        public string GPS { get { return _GPS; } set { _GPS = value; } }
        public string Music { get { return _Music; } set { _Music = value; } }
        public string FogLights { get { return _FogLights; } set { _FogLights = value; } }
        public string Spolier { get { return _Spoiler; } set { _Spoiler = value; } }
        public string NeonLight { get { return _NeonLight; } set { _NeonLight = value; } }
    }
}
```

And in your page, you could try this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        gv.DataSource = Car.GetCars();
        gv.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Since you have a collection property, it is not possible to show it in a column because you can have many items. In this case, a Nested GridView could help you, but you have to define properties in the gridview. See this sample:

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Nested-GridView-Example-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx

Comment: This works for me. But it should return 4 columns. That is "Model", "CarType","Accessories" and "Price". But only returns 3. "Accessories" column does not appear in GridView. Any idea?

Comment: It is another list, you have to have another grid to show this list.

Comment: I was thinking of this to show in same row using another GridView but I'm not sure how to do this. Can you please provide an example?

Comment: You could try a master/detail, for sample: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa581796.aspx

Comment: master/detail is not possible. I do not have primary key in the records. Isn't there any way to show Accessories columns in same row along with other 3 columns

Comment: Well, since you have a collection property, you can use a Nested GridView. Look it: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Nested-GridView-Example-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91257/discussion-between-kamalpreet-and-felipe-oriani).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution. The columns to be generated the engine should find any accessible properties.

```
private List<Accessories> _accessory;

public string Model { get; set; }
public string CarType { get; set; }
public List<Accessories> Accessory
{
    get { return _accessory ?? (__accessory = new List<Accessories>();)}
}
public string Price { get; set; }
```

Comment: It works. but It only binds "Model", "CarType" and "Price" columns to GridView. Why Accessory is not binding?

Comment: The error said - "any property or attribute". Here you have created properties. What are attributes and can we use them here?